# For ggplot2 geom_boxplot, is there a way to remove the box and whiskers when only 2 samples?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have encountered an issue with geom_boxplot and ggplot2 when a specific group has only a few samples in it. When there are a small number of samples in a group, the geom_boxplot command from ggplot2 still generates the box and whiskers, creating a view that gives quartiles even when they are not appropriate.

I am hopeful someone knows a way to force ggplot2 to not draw the box and whiskers for groups with a small number of samples.

Here is a toy example to show the issue.

```
###Example
library(ggplot2)

#Set DF for plot 
Num <- c(150, 196, 182, 224, 111, 129, 80, 183, 130, 171, 169, 165)
Group <- c("Three", "Three", "One", "Two", "One", "Two", "One", "Two", "One", "Two", "One", "Two")
DF <- data.frame(Num, Group)

#Make figure
p1 <- ggplot(DF, aes(Group, Num))
p1 + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Group)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("#CC0000", "#0000E5", "#008000")) + theme_minimal() + scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,17,15)) +
geom_point(size = 2.5) + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("One", "Two", "Three")).
```

Currently, this outputs the following figure, but there are only two samples under the "Three" group. Is there a way to force a specific group to only show the points if there are less than N samples in a group?

[image: CurrentOutputOfCode]

For this figure, I would expect groups One and Two to look like they do, but would expect group Three to only have the two points, nothing else. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is certainly to give `geom_boxplot` only the rows of data you want to plot by pre-computing the number of points:

```
DF$n = with(DF, ave(Num, Group, FUN = length))
## if you like dplyr
# DF = group_by(DF, Group) %>% mutate(n = n())

ggplot(DF, aes(Group, Num)) +
  geom_boxplot(data = subset(DF, n > 2), aes(fill = Group)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#CC0000", "#0000E5", "#008000")) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17, 15)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("One", "Two", "Three"))
```

[image]

Comment: A sidenote: the `group_by(DF, Group) %>% mutate(n = n())` may also be written `add_count(DF, Group)`.